# LSTM Data preparation

Tags: python, keras

I'm preparing a time series for an LSTM network (using Python and Keras) and it goes something like this:

```
Samples=[]
for i in range(0,len(TrainingData)-Time_Step,1):
    Samples.append(TrainingData[i:i+Time_Step])]
```

As it's a for loop its really slow, is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: Data for LSTM should have shapes like `(batch_size_or_samples, time_steps_or_length, features)`. The sequences should not be divided in windows (unless you strictly need this for very special reasons) and the time dimension should be the second, not the first.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do should be a simple reshape:

```
#if training data is not numpy, make it numpy
TrainingData = np.array(TrainingData)

originalShape = TrainindData.shape

if len(originalShape == 1):
    Samples = TrainingData.reshape((Time_Step,)) #or (Time_Step,1)
else:
    Samples = TrainingData.reshape((Time_Step,) + originalShape[1:])
```

Warning: Data for LSTM should have shapes like `(batch_size_or_samples, time_steps_or_length, features)`. The sequences should not be divided in windows (unless you strictly need this for very special reasons - and then you have to take some special actions too) and the time dimension should be the second, not the first.